# How to get all points along a way from (osm)PostGIS?

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I have import OpenstreetMap data into Postgres with gis extension with tool osm2pgsql (-s option)

of course, I have the following tables

```
planet_osm_point
planet_osm_ways
....
```

Within planet_osm_ways I have a column called way, type geometry(LineString, 4326), content like following

```
"0102000020E6100000070000005E70BCF1A49F2540D3D226987B134840896764EB749F25403B5DCC858013484040D1860D609F2540C426327381134840CE50DCF1269F2540EF552B137E1348405AAB2CC02D9E2540F978324976134840D66F26A60B9D2540CE8877256E1348403CA81F2FFF9C2540BC1D86FB6D134840"
```

What is that ? How could I get all points along this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's hex-encoded [extended well-known binary (EWKB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_binary) of a LINESTRING.

There are several methods to get the points along the way. To get individual coordinates as points, use [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html). Or to simply output the geometry in other human-readable formats (WKT, EWKT, GeoJSON, GML, etc.), see [the relevant manual section](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs).