# How to create a geometry in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I wan to create a geometry from follow format (I don't know what they call in postgrsql) using postgresql and it's spatial extension (postGIS). How should I do?

```
"01050000A0E6100000060000000102000080110000009E2FC6944A155D40478D54FFE6FE43400000000000A06740C2DF2F664B155D40D74CBED9E6FE43400000000000A06740BBEEAD484C155D4066D993C0E6FE434000000000008067406D37C1374D155D40137F1475E6FE43400000000000606740026729594E155D404FB1"
```

Comment: Are you sure that this data is correct? It looks like the output from a call to ST_GeomFromText() if so it can be reversed with ST_AsText() however an error is the result.

Comment: Ooooh your right. I was mixed up. "ST_AsText() " is what i need. TNX @ e4c5

Comment: Pretty much the [same answer here applies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32059133/327026), except this hex-encoded EWKB is invalid, since it is only 256-characters and not longer.